# TCP reassembly not happening with windows APIs in WINDOWS APPLICATION .NET

Tags: .net, windows, tcp

I refereed to answer on : "https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192251/always-stay-connected-mechanism-for-socket-connection"

I changed byte array size to 5000.

But now the problem is, I am not able to get all data on "BwReceiver_DoWork", I am getting segments, can you please tell me how to "reassembly" those segments.

I am connecting to a actual hardware, where I am sending a request and I should get response of 4096 bytes. Here I am not getting full payload at a time. I am getting 1440,1440 and 1287 in three different segments.

FYI : First segments containing header information, while next segments are not containing header information.

Please help me to reassemble all segments.

Comment: For TCP/IP you can never rely on receiving a particular chunk of data. All you know is you'll receive everyting (eventually), else you'll get an error, and that all packets are in order. You'll have to handle buffering until you have received the number of bytes you need in order to process the message.

Comment: These packets are not coming in order as we are sending continues request to the hardware.

Comment: I meant that the receiving side gets the packets in the order that the sender sent them. This is guaranteed by TCP/IP.